# Difference between "low-cost" and "cheap"

Tags: differences

Looking into definitions of "*low-cost*" by [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/low-cost)

> cheap

and [Marriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/low%E2%80%93cost)

> obtainable at low cost

it is not clear for me, how it is different from "*cheap*".

Was the term needed to avoid negative connotation of "*cheap*" as being of low quality (so it's an equivalent to "*not expensive*", just shorter)?

Comment: Cheap is often *cheap and nasty*, but things like *low-cost housing* are generally perceived to be either neutrally descriptive, or a desirable thing. It's all a matter of opinion and *precise* context, though.

Comment: Consider *A cheap substitute* and *a low cost substitute*. Low-cost has connotations of lingering value to it, whereas *cheap* suggests shoddy or shanty items.

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/low%E2%80%93cost) actually defines low-cost (adj) as 'obtainable at a low cost', avoiding the synonym 'cheap'. This is because 'cheap' also has the other sense Fumble Fingers mentions, and this connotation is perhaps difficult to filter out even when not intended.

Comment: Usage: *low-cost* is neutral in tone; *cheap* is a potentially loaded term.  Not just because of what you said about low quality, but also that the person involved (in either the foreground or the background) might be cheap, like the millionaire John D. Rockefeller making his four children share one tricycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**Cheap**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/cheap_1) : ( macmillandictionary.com)
>
> 1. not expensive;  used about something that is lower in price than usual or than you expected
> 2. not expensive and not of good quality; a cheap imitation.
> 3. a cheap action or remark is unfair or unkind and does not deserve respect; a cheap joke/jibe, a cheap trick.
> 4. not considered important or valuable.
> 5. (mainly American) not willing to spend money.
>
> **[low-cost](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/low-cost)**: (en.oxforddictionaries.com)
>
> Relatively inexpensive; cheap.

**Cheap** has a wide variety of meanings compared to **low-cost** and they can probably be synonymous only in the sense of **inexpensive.**

Answer (score 0):

Cheap in my experience is low cost and can also mean low quality. A "bargain" may be a better word for something of good quality but low price. Clothing that is cheap has a negative connotation like you get what you pay for vs. clothing that is a bargain is worth more than you paid.